# How to force the user to downgrade ssl certificate?

Tags: tls

In the [POODLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) attack the attacker needs MITM for forcing the user to downgrade the Certificate. For example, if the client is using TLS v1.0, then through the use of MTIM attacker needs to downgrade the SSL/TLS certificate to SSL3.

**How can an attacker downgrade the SSL/TLS certificate to SSL3 after getting successfully MITM if the client uses TLS 1.1 or 1.2?**

Comment: The answer is found in the link you posted and in the many referenced documents on that wiki. The attacker drops certain packets.

Comment: Instead of searching for "POODLE", search for the terms you used in your title: "downgrade ssl" - you will find tons of materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... forcing the user to downgrade the Certificate

A certificate can not be downgraded. It is independent from the SSL/TLS version used. Given that fPOODLE attack works against issues with SSL 3.0 (and some bugs in specific TLS 1.0 implementations too) the attacker needs instead force the clients to do a SSL/TLS handshake with protocol version SSL 3.0 instead of newer TLS versions.

At the time POODLE was invented the browsers typically automatically retried with a lower SSL/TLS version if the original connection failed in order to work around broken servers. Thus all the attacker had to do was to drop some packets, send a RST or similar so that the original attempt (which might have been done with TLS 1.2) failed and the browser automatically retried with SSL 3.0. This does not work any longer with most current browsers since these both no longer automatically downgrade and also have SSL 3.0 disabled.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, browsers automatically retried with lower Certificates if the server failed to fulfill the original request so attacker sends fake RST packet (as he is doing MITM right now) so it forces to use lower certificate, and hence SSL3 have a vulnerability in the cipher mode, an attacker can read the communication.?

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal: again, there is no such thing as lower certificates. The browser retried with a lower SSL/TLS protocol version which has nothing to do with certificates. But yes, once the attacker was able to use a lower protocol version SSL 3.0 the POODLE attack could be done.

Comment: Yes, my mean there for a lower certificate is lower protocol. Well, now I learned how poodle works. Great. Thanks, Steffen. :)